# Get json response through custom api endpoint

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I am creating a custom api endpoint to receive some data in json format. This is my module's code

**webapi.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
<route url="/V1/matrid-nextapi/orders" method="POST">
    <service class="Matrid\NextApi\Api\OrdersManagementInterface" method="postOrders"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Matrid\NextApi\Api\OrdersManagementInterface" type="Matrid\NextApi\Model\OrdersManagement"/>
</config>
```

**Api/OrdersManagementInterface.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Matrid\NextApi\Api;

interface OrdersManagementInterface
{

    /**
     * 
     * @param mixed $Orders
     * @return mixed[]
     */
    public function postOrders($Orders);
}
```

**Model/OrdersManagement.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Matrid\NextApi\Model;

class OrdersManagement implements \Matrid\NextApi\Api\OrdersManagementInterface
{

    /**
    *
    * @param mixed $Orders
    * @return mixed[]
    */
    public function postOrders($Orders)
    {
        return $Orders;
    }
}
```

Now I have created a script on magento root and try to hit this api using curl. I am expecting to get the posted array as result but I am getting an error message as response.

This is my custom script to check that is placed on magento root.

```
**custom-script.php**

<?php
$data = array (
      "Orders"=> [
            "ID"=> 1000006636,
            "Brand"=> "Brand",
      ]
    );

$ch = curl_init("https://staging.nonnon.co.uk/index.php/rest/V1/matrid-nextapi/orders");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($data))));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo "<pre>";print_r($result);
```

?>

This script is giving me output as

```
{"message":"\"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.","parameters":{"fieldName":"data"}}
```

I need the $data array as the output. I am not sure what I have missed as this is my first time working with magento apis. Could someone guide me in the right direction.
I just need $data as the response and then I will manipulate it according to my requirements.

**Update**
According to @Konrad Siamro, I have made some changes to my code.
I have also changed $data to $Orders in Api/OrdersManagementInterface.php and also in Model/OrdersManagement.php
Updated code for

```
**custom-script.php**
<?php
$data = array (
  'Orders' => 
    array (
     0 => 
      array (
       'ID' => 19558599,
       'Brand' => 'Brand',
       'Destination' => 'NextRDC',
       'DateTimeStamp' => '2021-01-05T20:37:29+00:00',
       'Currency' => 'GBP',
       'Items' => 
          array (
           0 => 
            array (
             'ItemID' => 12345678,
             'EAN' => '1234567890123',
             'BrandSKU' => '12345678',
             'Quantity' => 1,
             'PromiseDate' => '2021-01-09',
             'Price' => 67,
           ),
        ),
     ),
  ),
);

$ch = curl_init("https://staging.nonnon.co.uk/index.php/rest/V1/matrid-nextapi/orders");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($data))));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($result);
```

Now after running this script the output that I am getting is this

```
string(243) "[{"ID":19558599,"Brand":"Brand","Destination":"NextRDC","DateTimeStamp":"2021-01-05T20:37:29+00:00","Currency":"GBP","Items":[{"ItemID":12345678,"EAN":"1234567890123","BrandSKU":"12345678","Quantity":1,"PromiseDate":"2021-01-09","Price":67}]}]"
```

But now the problem is I am getting the json input as an string form. My question is how I can get it in json format.

Comment: Hey, You need to add to Your Post Request BODY with parameter name You are using in Your Endpoint. In this case, You definied parameter as $data. It meant that You need to send Body like {"data": <values for data>}. I think You dont need to use jsonDecode for that. Probably You will have more issues with return and echo, but try to send good parameter at first

Comment: @KonradSiamro I have made some changes to the code according to your suggestions, plz have a look and suggest How I can get the data in json format.

Comment: Json is basically a formatted string, you can use json_decode to convert the Json to an array when receiving the response from your API

Comment: @AlanZavagli ok and also the Orders key is getting ignored while fetching the data. You can see it in the string output. Can you suggest how I can preserve the Orders key also

Comment: When you fetch the data, you cicle the orders and print each one of them? I've done some testing with your json and seems all good to me